# getVoices not working as expected now but it worked a month ago

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api

I want to use Web Speech API so first I need to list all available voices using this function:

```js
getAllVoices();

function getAllVoices() {
  loadVoices();
  window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = loadVoices;

  function loadVoices() {
    const voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    console.log(voices.map(voice => voice.name));
  }
}
```

The issue is I have installed Ivona voices in my machine but none of the Ivona voices show up in the returned array?!

The wired part is this used to work fine and I used Ivona voices with the same function a month ago!!! but know the chrome cannot find any Ivona voices?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe your test version of ivona is expired?

Comment: No...it doesn't